# Pygame overlapping Sprites (draw order) based on location

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection, draw

I'm still relatively new to Pygame and Python in general, so hopefully this isn't too out there.

I'm making a top-down RPG, and I have two Sprite objects with images that look (for example) like these:
[image] [image]

that use rects that do not represent the entirety of the image:

```
class NPC(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pygame.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.collisionRect = pygame.Rect(self.rect.left, self.rect.top + 12, self.image.get_width(), self.image.get_width()) 
        #12 is the number of pixels that will overlap in the y-dimension
```

I'm doing this because I want the top few pixels of the NPC to overlap with other sprites. The `collisionRect` in each object is used over the `rect` whenever I detect a collision, so that I can create this effect.

However, I need a way to redraw them within my update() function so that one draws over the other *based on their relative locations to each other.*

So, when one NPC is above the other it looks like this:

[image]

But, when it's the other way around, it should look like this:

[image]

Which means that the images need to be drawn in a different order depending on which sprite is 'below' the other.

I've thought about possibly cutting the sprites into separate sprites and just have the 'head' sprites draw last, but I was wondering if there was a simpler (or at least a reliable) way to *detect* whether a sprite should be drawn last or not, based on whether or not it is both overlapping another sprite *and* immediately below it in the y-dimension.

I apologize if this question is too broad or needs more context; can provide those if needed.

Comment: Nice sprite bitmaps!  Can you not sort your sprites by their `Y` co-ordinate, and then paint the lower-Y sprites first?   Or, detect overlap using the normal collision routines, and sort out the z-ordering when detected?

Comment: Huh, that's a good idea! I was thinking about handling it with collisions, but that makes more sense than what I had in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Kingsley already said in a comment, sorting your sprites by their `y` coordinate is a common way to do this.

Here's a full, running example (I named your images `guy.png` and `gal.png`). Since you already use sprites, I used a simple `pygame.sprite.Group`-subclass:

```
import pygame

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(pos)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)

    def update(self, events, dt):
        pass

class Player(Actor):
    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        super().__init__(image, pos)

    def update(self, events, dt):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        move = pygame.Vector2((0, 0))
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: move += (0, -1)
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: move += (-1, 0)
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: move += (0, 1)
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: move += (1, 0)
        if move.length() > 0: move.normalize_ip()
        self.pos += move*(dt/5)
        self.rect.center = self.pos

class YAwareGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def by_y(self, spr):
        return spr.pos.y

    def draw(self, surface):
        sprites = self.sprites()
        surface_blit = surface.blit
        for spr in sorted(sprites, key=self.by_y):
            self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
        self.lostsprites = []

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0

    sprites = YAwareGroup(Player(pygame.image.load('guy.png').convert_alpha(), (100, 200)),
                          Actor(pygame.image.load('gal.png').convert_alpha(), (200, 200)))

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites.update(events, dt)
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprites.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

If you need custom drawing logic, it's usually not the worst idea to subclass pygame's `Group` classes. You can find their source [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame) to see how they work.