# Implementing layers when blitting an object in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I can't find an answer to this anywhere else but it seems to be such an obvious and necessary feature for game design that I can't imagine an implementation for it doesn't exist. I'm attempting to blit an already-created object onto the screen, however the argument I'm using for blitting does not seem to contain a space to specify what layer the sprite should be displayed on, instead displaying an error message stating "invalid rectstyle argument". If it does indeed turn out that there is no way for the standard blit() function to include layers, I would appreciate it if I could have a workaround that works in the context of object-oriented programming. Code below for context:

```py
class Hud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, group, layer, posX, posY):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Hudplaceholder.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(posX, posY))
        self._layer = layer
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, group)

    class Health(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, group, layer, posX, posY):
            self.image = pygame.image.load("Healthplaceholder.png")
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(posX, posY))
            self._layer = layer
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, group)
    #all of the other sprites are in the same format
    
    #global sprite dump
    group = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    hud = Hud(group, 3, 655, 5)
    health = Health(group, 3, 790, 135)
    ammo = Ammo(group, 3, 795, 190)
    eye1 = Eye1(group, 3, 790, 250)
    desk = Desk1(group, 2, 409, 230)
    interior = Interior(group, 0, 410, 180)
    shelf = Shelf(group, 2, 409, 230)
    drinksMachine = DrinksMachine(group, 2, 409, 230)
    deskUnder = DeskUnder(group, 2, 409, 230)
    rifle = Gun(group, 4, 220, 250)

    group.add(hud)
    group.add(health)
    group.add(ammo)
    group.add(eye1)
    group.add(desk)
    group.add(interior)
    group.add(queueCustomer)

    screen.blit(interior.image, (-20, -20))
    screen.blit(desk.image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(hud.image, (hud.rect.centerx, hud.rect.centery))
    screen.blit(health.image, (756, 110))
    screen.blit(health.image, (706, 110))
    screen.blit(health.image, (656, 110))
    screen.blit(ammo.image, (765, 155))
    screen.blit(ammo.image, (725, 155))
    screen.blit(ammo.image, (685, 155))
    screen.blit(ammo.image, (645, 155))
    screen.blit(eye1.image, (750, 220))
    group.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Why are you manually blitting your layered sprites instead of using [`group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.draw)?

Comment: The code needs to paint the screen from the background through to the foreground.  The concept of layers, is known as "z-order".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pygame overlapping Sprites (draw order) based on location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233448/pygame-overlapping-sprites-draw-order-based-on-location)

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to forgo using the excellent sprite group drawing functions, a simple method to do this might be:

1. Create a list of all Sprites: `all_sprites`.
2. Sort your list of Sprites by their `_layer`
3. Paint them individually

```
    all_sprites = [ hud, health, ammo, etc. ]

    # ... 
   
    # sort sprites by ascending _layer
    for sprite in sorted( all_sprites, key=lambda x: x._layer ):
        # and then paint
        screen.blit( sprite.image, sprite.rect )
```

That said, you probably don't need to do this.  Probably a bit of re-work on your painting algorithm would remove the necessity.